# Error JAVA No se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: java

Estoy empezando con un curso de JAVA por mi cuenta y no para de salirme este error pese a mis intentos de editar PATH y CLASSPATH (que es donde he leído reside el problema).

He instalado el JDK y está bien instalado porque al escribir javac en el CMD aparece una lista de posibles comandos.

He configurado en variables JAVA_HOME, PATH (/bin) y CLASSPATH (/lib). Creo un programa llamado MiModulo.java (lo edito en el bloc de notas y lo guardo como MiModulo.java):

```
/**
* La clase MiModulo implementa una aplicación que
* simplemente imprime "Módulo profesional - Programación" en pantalla.
*/
classMiModulo {
publicstaticvoidmain(String[] args) {
System.out.println("Móduloprofesional -Programación");
// Muestra la cadena de caracteres.
}
}
```

Al intentar correrlo en el CMD con javacMiModulo.java me salta lo siguiente:

"No se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable"

He estado quitando las rutas en las variables, volviéndolas a poner etc. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Buenas, bienvenido al sitio. No sé si es un fallo al copiar los textos aquí pero no estás dejando espacios en varios sitios. Ni en el código ni en el comando ejecutado. `javacMiModulo.java` debería ser `javac MiModulo.java` y ser lanzado en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra el fichero MiModulo.java. El fichero debería además tener los espacios correctos.

Comment: Por otro lado ningún programador java usa el bloc de notas. Deberías investigar el uso de algún IDE como Eclipse o IntelliJ.

Comment: Hola, sé que el bloc de notas no es lo mejor pero estoy siguiendo al pie de la letra los apuntes.

Comment: Vale, el problema era los espacios al intentar compilar, pero ahora me sale otro mensaje diferente: error: file not found: MiModulo.java

Comment: Pues eso es lo que te comentaba, debes ejecutar el comando en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra el fichero MiModulo.java

Comment: Lo he guardado en C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documentos; pero mi pregunta es: ¿no se supone que no hace falta especificar la ruta cada vez que quieras compilar o ejecutar un programa java si ya has especificado PATH?

Comment: La guía en cuestión es esta:
http://programacionparaprogramadores.blogspot.com/2013/04/codificacion-compilacion-y-ejecucion-de.html

Comment: No hace falta que especifiques la ruta donde está el comando javac (o java, que es el que usarás a continuación) pero la ruta donde se encuentra el fichero que quieres compilar sí tienes que indicarla o posicionarte en el directorio donde se encuentre. El comando no busca en todo tu disco duro hasta encontrar el fichero.

Comment: No sé cómo hacer eso; en el artículo solo te dice que lo compiles desde la carpeta pero no te dice cómo: Accede a la consola de comandos de Windows y teclea, en la carpeta donde has guardado el archivo Java, el comando para compilarlo: Javac MiModulo.java. ¿Es en la línea de ruta, arriba del todo?

Comment: La "guía" te indica lo mismo que yo: "en la carpeta donde has guardado el archivo Java". Suponiendo que cmd ya se te abra en C:\Users\User, solo tienes que teclear `cd OneDrive\Documentos` y pulsar Intro. Y luego escribes `javac MiModulo.java` y vuelves a pulsar intro. Si a continuación escribes `dir` debería salirte un nuevo fichero `MiModulo.class`

Comment: Vale, he aplicado cd C:\Users\Super\OneDrive\Documentos y una vez 'dentro' he puesto "java MiModulo.java", apareciéndome lo que había dentro de la class. No conocía el comando cd porque no aparecía por ningún lado en la guía.

Gracias, solucionado.

Comment: Si siguiendo los apuntes al pie de la letra te pide que uses el bloc de notas para escribir codigo -> deja el curso, busca otro y denúnciales por fraude.

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, tu código no esta separado por espacios, nose si es un error que has tenido al escribir la pregunta o si tienes el codigo escrito de esta forma...

El código debería verse así :

```
class MiModulo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Móduloprofesional -Programación");
   }
}
```

Segundo, no utilices bloc de notas para programar... Para eso existen los IDE's (Entornos de desarollo integrados) que te ayudarán a realizar la sintaxis del codigo y compilar el progama (ejecutarlo).

Sobre los IDE's, personalmente te recomiendo Eclipse. Desde aquí puedes dirigirte a descargarlo. https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

En caso de querer investigar otro tipo de IDE tienes otros como :

> *Apache Netbeans, IntelliJ, Greenfoot, jGRASP etc...*

Aquí tienes un video que te ayudará a la instalación de Eclipse en caso que tengas problemas para ello... Y verás como ejecutar el primer programa como el que tienes.

[Link video de instalación y ejecución del primer programa con Eclipse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqqFO2Z5jKU)

Para compilar ("ejecutar") tu archivo java solo deberás dar click en el botón que se ve en la siguiente imagen :

[image: Run]

Comment: Cualquier duda, o si esto no soluciona tu problema escribe un comentario.

Comment: Importante: No es lo mismo compilar que ejecutar. Lo repites un par de veces en tu texto.

Comment: Lo se, la compilación es la traducción del lenguaje para que la máquina entienda el código. De todas formas, no creo que sea necesario su explicación, lo he puesto entre `" "` precisamente por eso. Un saludo!

Comment: Hombre, por línea de comandos se emplean dos comandos distintos: javac (para compilar, generar los ficheros .class) y java (para ejecutar). Lo de las comillas sigue sin convencerme, en la primera mención ni siquiera aparecen, igualas los dos términos. Son dos conceptos básicos diferentes que no se deben confundir.

Comment: Sugiere una edición a la respuesta.